# Remove duplicated records based on pair of columns?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a table with the folowwing columns:

```
id
app_id
tag_id
created_at
updated_at
```

The pair `app_id` and `tag_id` should be uniq. How to remove oldest duplicated records based on `updated_at` column to determine "oldest" and pair `(app_id, tag_id)` to determine "duplicated"?

Comment: Write a rake task to do it.

Comment: @p4sh4 Yeah, the question is about how to do it using ActiveRecord

Comment: You can use ActiveRecord in rake tasks.

Comment: @p4sh4 I know where I should write the task, I don't know what to write

Comment: @Jess Can you make your question lil bit more clear.? Like do you want to delete all records which are created a particular date and whose `app_id` & `tag_id` are same.?

Comment: @ynos1234 I want to delete all record with the same `app_id` and `tag_id` but leave the last one record

Answer (score 2):

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
   delete from my_table where id in (
     select t1.id
     from my_table t1
     inner join (
       select app_id, tag_id, min(updated_at) as oldest
       from my_table
       group by app_id, tag_id
     ) t2 
     on t1.app_id = t2.app_id 
     and t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id
     and t1.updated_at = t2.oldest
   )
 SQL
```

Replace `my_table` with your actual table name.